# SQL Server enabling page level locks on all of a databases's indexes

Tags: sql-server, locking

Good day everyone. Recently, our maintenance plan that reorganizes indexes has been throwing errors, and it's because page level locks have been disabled on some indexes for unknown reasons. The job stops after 2 indexes have failed, so I keep on having to run the job to find out which queries have their page locks disabled. It seems only two databases have their indexes' page locks disabled.

Is it possible to enable page level locks on all indexes of a database via a query? There's a lot tables and doing it manually is a pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try the following script to find them:

```
select
  i.name AS index_name,
  object_schema_name(i.object_id) as table_schema,
  object_name(i.object_id) as table_name,
  i.*,
  'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(i.name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(object_schema_name(i.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(object_name(i.object_id)) + ' SET (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON); ' AS command_to_rebuild
from sys.indexes i
where
    i.allow_page_locks = 0
    and i.is_disabled = 0
    and type not in (5) --not columnstore
```

In the last column you will find the command to change this configuration.
I have not tried this script with all index types, so I invite you to evaluate the list produced.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot!